# Android Studio Trying to run my first Hello World

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.1

I just downloaded Android Studio 4.1.1 and my goal is to run "Hello World!" on a Pixel 3 emulator. I tried just opening a basic barebones app and I get the following error. This appears quite odd as I haven't touched any of the default settings. Is there something I am missing here? Do I still need to install something else? I am running java 15.0.1. Something tells me there are two non-compatible programs that I am running. Any advice is helpful.Do I need to just try downloading an older version of Android Studio.
Thank you.

> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.1.1-6503028.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.1.1-6503028.
> > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/4.1.1-6503028/aapt2-4.1.1-6503028.pom
> > Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: Yeah Android Studio only supports Java 8.  Install JDK 8, set JAVA_HOME to point to JDK 8 folder and restart machine

Comment: Thanks @DavidKroukamp I tried this, but it didn't help my issues :/

Comment: Also now that you corrected the java home try a new project from scratch just to be sure

Comment: yes. same errors

Comment: Try deleting the gradle cache (just delete the whole .gradle directory), see if that helps. Looks like the downloaded POM file got corrupted.